# Do the functions in libpcap and winpcap have identical names?

Tags: c++, pcap, winpcap, libpcap

Do the functions in libpcap and winpcap have identical names? If not, what names are different, or are the majority of them different?

Also, can libpcap++ be used for winpcap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WinPcap website](http://www.winpcap.org/) says:

> This library also contains the Windows
>   version of the well known libpcap Unix
>   API.

So it looks like the answer should be they are about the same.  As for whether libpcap++ can be used with WinPcap, why don't you give it a quick try and let us know?  If it doesn't work, you might look at this: http://www.flexbyte.com/winpcap-cpp-wrapper/

Comment: Yes - WinPcap is best thought of as a port of libpcap to Windows; it has a few Windows-specific APIs added (dealing with HANDLEs), and is missing some UN\*X-specific APIs (dealing with UN\*X-style file descriptors), and has a few other additions.  The current version of WinPcap isn't based on the latest libpcap, so it doesn't have all of the APIs that the latest libpcap does.  (Hopefully this will change at some point; that requires some libpcap work to allow it to, for example, handle remote capture.)